# Need to run a Gradle task after Android APK generated through Studio Build menu, but not when deploying/testing a release build on local device

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I'm not 100% certain this is possible, but I have set up a gradle task that tags my git repo with info about the build, which runs when I generate my signed apk just before releasing. I generate the apk using the Android Studio Build -> Generate signed bundle/apk menu option (mainly because it has all my keystore info in it and it's easy to do).

However, when I sometimes test the release build of my app, rather than the debug build, and I run it on my phone plugged in, just by clicking the green 'play' triangle button, it also tags the current git head with the same info.

Is there any gradle task that runs purely when I do the Generate signed bundle/apk menu option? I don't know of anyway of finding it out.

I feel like the only task there might be is some sort of signing task. Unless when i test on my device, it's also signing the apk, in which case...how? I'm 99% certain i don't have my keystore password anywhere so it couldn't use it...could it?

**EDIT** It appears I do use a plain text file called keystore.properties which has all my keystore details in it (I made it over 2yrs ago so forgot all about it!), so this must be being used for the release build. So in fact is there no diff between me testing my release build (and the apk it generates) and running Build -> Generate apk?

Thanks

Comment: check the type of build before posting

Comment: but there are only two build types, debug and release. (right?) and generating the apk, makes the release build, and testing the release build on my phone ALSO uses the release build

Comment: no while you test on device its the debug build type and when you intentionally build a realse type then only its release build. so before posting things to your github check the build type and you can achieve what you wnat to achievve

Comment: No you can definitely test release builds on a device. Under Android Studio you go to the builds option in the bottom right, and select release.

Comment: yes you can do that but it increases build time and so the productivity goes down so by default the build tyoe that is installed on your phone is debug.